# Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK Refresh install issue on Visual Studio 2010 Professional Beta 2

Tags: windows-mobile, visual-studio-2010

When I install the **Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK Refresh** I get the error:

**Not Installed: Visual Studio 2005 SP1 or Later**

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional Beta 2 installed.

Please can you tell me how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Visual Studio 2008, smart device development is not yet supported in VS2010 (well it definitely wasn't supported in beta 1, and I have seen anything contrary so far for beta 2)

VS2008 and VS2010 will co-exist on the same machine.

Comment: Is this really the answer? Where am I supposed to find a legit vs2008 install?

Comment: Yep it is. You can download vs2008 from msdn subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's any workaround for this particular case, but Visual Studio and its add-ons are in general notorious for requiring exact versions of all dependencies, leading to conflicts that often make it impossible to install the versions you want of everything.

Personally I keep a virtual machine for each Visual Studio environment to keep the dependencies happy. You might benefit from running either VS2010 or VS2005 or both in a VirtualBox/VirtualPC/VMware.

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste your time installing 2008!

You can override this in the installation file:

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_SDK_7.1_does_not_install_in_Windows_XP_(Known_Issue)

Extract the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 install file to a directory via unzip tool;

Edit the **baseline.dat** in the directory like this

...

[gencomp7788]

...

InstallOnWinXP=0

REM original is InstallOnWinXP=1

...

and save;

Run the setup.exe of the directory with paremeter via running utility or command line of start menu .

For example
X:\xx\setup.exe /web

The error message, for failing to meet system requirement, won't pop up again and the installation continues.