# Best way to write a Mobile 6 app with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: mobile, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-6.1

I need to write a simple app for a [Symbol MC70 scanner](http://www.nationalbarcode.com/Symbol/Symbol-MC70-Specifications.htm)

My device is loaded with: Microsoft Windows Mobile 6.1 Premium

I have VS 2010 Premium on my desktop.
When installing the  Window Mobile 6 SDK I get this error:
[image]

I read this article:
[Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK Refresh install issue on Visual Studio 2010 Professional Beta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779874/windows-mobile-6-standard-sdk-refresh-install-issue-on-visual-studio-2010-profess)

**But my question is really - What's the best way to go forward from here?**
Using WinForms I can knock this app out in 3 hours. I'm hoping I don't burn 3 days fooling around with SDK's etc. **Does anyone know if there are any VS 2010 plugins for this?**
Would it be best to try and update the devise to Mobile 7 and use VS 2010?

Thanks so much for any help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MC70 device does not support wm7 and vs2010 does not support wm6 development.

The only current solution I'm aware off is to develop with vs2008.

Answer (score 4):

The *only* solution is to install Visual Studio 2008 Professional and create a WinForms Smat Device app.

Comment: Wicked Smat! Who's from Boston :)